# unable to access typeScript object value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in Angular 8. I have a model class named `Basic`, to hold the basic information of a profile. 
In my component, a object of `Basic` type will be returned from `Service`, the service will get values from server. In my component when i am printing the object of `Basic`, it is showing that there is values, but when i am trying to access those values it is showing undefined. My `Basic` class has getter/setter.

**Service Code**

```
bas: Basic = new Basic();

  public getCurrentUserBasic() {
    return this.http.get<Basic>(
      'http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/profile/basic/findOneByUser', this.authService.getHeader(),
    ).subscribe((b: Basic) => {
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(b);

      // phone number
      for (const key in b['phone_number']) {
        const phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
        phoneNumber.$id = b['phone_number'][key]['id'];
        phoneNumber.$number = b['phone_number'][key]['number'];
        this.phoneNumbers.push(phoneNumber);
      }

      // basic information
      this.bas.$id = b['id'];
      this.bas.$name = b['name'];
      this.bas.$birthDate = b['birthDate'];
      this.bas.$gender = b['gender'];
      this.bas.$blood_Group = b['blood_Group'];
      this.bas.$religion = b['religion'];
      this.bas.$email = b['email'];
    });
  }// get current user basic.


public getBasicInformation() {
    return this.bas;
  }
```

**Component**

```
public setBasicInformation() {
    try {
      var basic: Basic = this.basicService.getBasicInformation();
      this.name = basic.$name;
      console.log(this.name);
      console.log('\n\n name : ' + basic['name']);
      console.log('\n\n $name : ' + basic.$name);
      this.birthDate = basic.$birthDate;
      this.gender = basic.$gender;
      console.log(basic);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error in Setting Basic Information!');
    }
  }
```

The below lines are printing `undefined`.

```
console.log(this.name);// should not work, as property is private in model class.
console.log('\n\n name : ' + basic['name']);
console.log('\n\n $name : ' + basic.$name);
```

While this `console.log(basic);` line's result is below : 
[image: Result of Basic]

**Model Class**

```
export class Basic {
  private id: string;
  private userId: string;
  private name: string;
  private birthDate: string;
  private care_of: string;
  private gender: string;
  private maritalStatus: string;
  private profession: string;
  private blood_Group: string;
  private available: string;
  private religion: string;
  private email: string;

  /**
   * Getter $id
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $id(): string {
    return this.id;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $userId
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $userId(): string {
    return this.userId;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $name
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $name(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $birthDate
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $birthDate(): string {
    return this.birthDate;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $care_of
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $care_of(): string {
    return this.care_of;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $gender
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $gender(): string {
    return this.gender;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $maritalStatus
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $maritalStatus(): string {
    return this.maritalStatus;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $profession
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $profession(): string {
    return this.profession;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $blood_Group
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $blood_Group(): string {
    return this.blood_Group;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $available
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $available(): string {
    return this.available;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $id
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $id(value: string) {
    this.id = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $userId
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $userId(value: string) {
    this.userId = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $name
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $name(value: string) {
    this.name = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $birthDate
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $birthDate(value: string) {
    this.birthDate = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $care_of
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $care_of(value: string) {
    this.care_of = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $gender
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $gender(value: string) {
    this.gender = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $maritalStatus
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $maritalStatus(value: string) {
    this.maritalStatus = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $profession
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $profession(value: string) {
    this.profession = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $blood_Group
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $blood_Group(value: string) {
    this.blood_Group = value;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $available
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $available(value: string) {
    this.available = value;
  }


  /**
   * Getter $religion
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $religion(): string {
    return this.religion;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $religion
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $religion(value: string) {
    this.religion = value;
  }

  /**
   * Getter $email
   * @return {string}
   */
  public get $email(): string {
    return this.email;
  }

  /**
   * Setter $email
   * @param {string} value
   */
  public set $email(value: string) {
    this.email = value;
  }

}//class
```

According to my knowledge these two lines should print values :

```
console.log('\n\n name : ' + basic['name']);
console.log('\n\n $name : ' + basic.$name);
```

while this `console.log(basic);` is printing values.

Comment: Try to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem, for example on stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are invoking `setBasicInformation()` before server has returned with the response in your `getCurrentUserBasic()` function.

In Javascript objects are passed by reference, your `var basic` in `setBasicInformation()`  refers to `this.bas` from your service.

When you a log an object on the console it will update the value of log when base object updates e.g. console.log (basic) will start reflecting the value of this.bas even on console as soon as it is updated in the service.

While same is not the case when console.log for strings, it will always log the absolute value at the time of console.log being invoked.

Following two lines log strings at the time where value of basic is null, hence they are logging undefined.

```
console.log('\n\n name : ' + basic['name']);
console.log('\n\n $name : ' + basic.$name);
```

Change your `setBasicInformation()` to set values in the subscribe fn of `getCurrentUserBasic` and pipe the values through `getBasicInformation()`

```
public getCurrentUserBasic() {
      return this.http.get<Basic>(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/profile/basic/findOneByUser', this.authService.getHeader())
    }


  public getBasicInformation( b ) {
        // phone number
        for (const key in b['phone_number']) {
          const phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
          phoneNumber.$id = b['phone_number'][key]['id'];
          phoneNumber.$number = b['phone_number'][key]['number'];
          this.phoneNumbers.push(phoneNumber);
        }

        // basic information
        this.bas.$id = b['id'];
        this.bas.$name = b['name'];
        this.bas.$birthDate = b['birthDate'];
        this.bas.$gender = b['gender'];
        this.bas.$blood_Group = b['blood_Group'];
        this.bas.$religion = b['religion'];
        this.bas.$email = b['email'];
      return this.bas;
    }

  public setBasicInformation() {
      try {
        this.basicService.getCurrentUserBasic().pipe ( map ( this.basicService.getBasicInformation ())).subscribe ( basic => {
          this.name = basic.$name;
          console.log(this.name);
          console.log('\n\n name : ' + basic['name']);
          console.log('\n\n $name : ' + basic.$name);
          this.birthDate = basic.$birthDate;
          this.gender = basic.$gender;
          console.log(basic);
        });

      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error in Setting Basic Information!');
      }
    }
```